# Sum quantity from table1 and Table2 then minus to see stock (Access SQL)

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have two table in an `Access` database. Both table structure is same. First table for transaction in and second table is for transaction out. I was trying to get total `Transaction In` and total `Transaction Out` for each item and then show `Stock`. See below screenshot of my tables structure and data.

[image]

I am using below query which give me wrong output.

```
SELECT TABLE1.ID, Sum(TABLE1.qty) AS TR_In, Sum(TABLE2.qty) AS TR_Out, Sum(TABLE1.qty)-Sum(TABLE2.qty) AS Stock
          FROM TABLE1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID
GROUP BY TABLE1.ID;
```

[image]

My expected output would be like following

[image]

### Table1 Data

| ID | Description | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| RM001 | Item1 | 3 |
| RM001 | Item1 | 3 |
| RM002 | Item2 | 2 |
| RM003 | Item3 | 1 |
| RM003 | Item3 | 1 |

### Table2 Data

| ID | Description | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| RM001 | Item1 | 1 |
| RM001 | Item1 | 1 |
| RM001 | Item1 | 1 |
| RM002 | Item2 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you join before aggregating, flip it to aggregate both tables before joining to avoid the double counting of matches ids:

```
SELECT agg1.id, agg1.TR_In, agg2.TR_Out, 
       (agg1.TR_In - NZ(agg2.TR_Out, 0)) AS Stock
FROM (SELECT TABLE1.ID, SUM(TABLE1.qty) AS TR_In 
      FROM TABLE1
      GROUP BY TABLE1.ID
     ) as agg1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT TABLE2.ID, SUM(TABLE2.qty) AS TR_Out 
      FROM TABLE2
      GROUP BY TABLE2.ID
     ) as agg2
     ON agg1.ID = agg2.ID
```

Comment: Do I need to change any part of your given code to run. While I was trying to run your code it gives me warning like this `The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is missspelled or missing, or punctuation is incorrect.`.

Comment: This won't deal with the null case properly. Since it is a left join, (and this is access) you need an `IIF` before the - agg2.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock I have tried with data for all 3 items in both table so, there is no chance to be null. Same warning message still.

Comment: @Harun24HR . . . The code wasn't quite down to the standards of MS Access.  I think I fixed it.  This would be the preferred solution as you have described the problem.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. Working off mobile device can bring strange punctuation.

Answer (score 2):

Use a union query and sum the output from this:

```sql
Select
    ID,
    Sum(TRIn) As TR_In,
    Sum(TROut) As TR_Out,
    Sum(Total) As Stock
From

(Select
    ID,
    Description,
    Qty As TRIn,
    0 As TROut,
    Qty As Total
From
    table1
Order By ID

Union All

Select
    ID,
    Description,
    0 As TRIn,
    Qty As TROut,
    -Qty As Total
From
    table2)

Group By
    ID
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of extraneous commas in Parfait's answer (after AS TR_In  … AS TR_Out) as well as the missing IIF.

In full the query should look like this:

```
SELECT agg1.id, agg1.TR_In, agg2.TR_Out, 
       (agg1.TR_In - IIF(agg2.TR_Out IS NULL, 0, agg2.TR_Out)) AS Stock
FROM
 (SELECT TABLE1.ID, SUM(TABLE1.qty) AS TR_In
  FROM TABLE1
  GROUP BY TABLE1.ID) agg1
LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT TABLE2.ID, SUM(TABLE2.qty) AS TR_Out
  FROM TABLE2
  GROUP BY TABLE2.ID) agg2
ON agg1.ID = agg2.ID
```

If you want you can also repeat the IIF for the second column, so that you get 0 instead of null.

Comment: Make sense. Now both solution (your and Parfait's)  working. Thanks for your effort. I also mange to user `IIF()` for `TR_OUT`. I am okay with `SQL` but I am not understanding use of `agg1` and `agg2` instead of table names. Can you please explain. My problem is solved with your solution.

Comment: agg1 and agg2 are simply aliases.  You can call them whatever you like (y and z would work equally well).  When doing sub-selects in this fashion, aliases are required.  It is usual practice to give the alias a meaningful name.  In this case I copied Parfait's nomenclature: he is using agg1 to represent "aggregate of Table1".